# Excel file into NSArray

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, csv, nsarray, xls

I have an Excel file whose data I need to use as a source for my table view. How can I convert the .xls into a plist file so I can parse it into NSArray? Does the Numbers app in iWork suite have this option?

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Read data from Excel file in Objective-C (iPhone)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3516129/read-data-from-excel-file-in-objective-c-iphone)

Answer (score 0):

The solution I’ve used in the past is to export the .xls as a tab-delimited file and then use e.g. a python script to convert from that to a plist. It’s pretty easy, though providing sample code to do it is difficult because it’s pretty problem-specific.

Answer (score 0):

If you can export it as a CSV or TSV file, you can use my [CHCSVParser](http://github.com/davedelong/CHCSVParser) to do all of the parsing work for you.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the reply. Does it work on iOS aswell? Thanks.

Comment: @user635064 if you click on the link, scroll down to the README, and look at the "Supported Platforms" section, you'll see "iOS 3+" listed there.