# iPhone - Parsing Excel files

Tags: iphone, excel

My CRM server is having all the information in excel files.
In my iphone application, i've to download them, parse the data and store them in database (sqllite or coredata)
I'm aware of how to populate coredate or database. But I didn't come across any library/framework that can parse excel files and extract data.
Is there any tutorial or 3rd party library for that?

Comment: I do not have any idea about XLS files(I will post if i can find something) but if you XLS file are simple(without formulas and macros) then converting then in csv would be very easy, then using CSV in iphone or anywhere is not a big deal.....

Comment: What language are you working in?  Most of the languages I know have some sort of library for reading and writing Excel files.

Comment: Hi Adamleerich, I'm using Objective C to code apps on iPhone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at this answer

[Read data from Excel file in Objective-C (iPhone)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3516129/read-data-from-excel-file-in-objective-c-iphone)

Objective-C does not have native support for reading Excel files.

But, you do not need to use Objective-C to populate your database, only to run the app on the iPhone.  You can use another scripting language (PHP, Ruby, Perl, etc.) to convert the Excel spreadhseets to tables in your database.

I would recommend doing the data transfer in Ruby using the spreadsheet gem.  It is documented here

http://rubyforge.org/projects/spreadsheet