# Export data to *.xls file by using xml to create the file on an iOS 5 App

Tags: ios, xml, export-to-excel, xls

I'm using the following code, to create an *.xls file on my iOS App. Everything is going right. I can open it with Microsoft Excel but, if I would like to open it with Apple Numbers, it doesn't work.

```
- (void)exportToExcel
{
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];

    NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];

    NSError *error;
    NSString *header = @"<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>\n<Workbook xmlns=\"urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet\"\nxmlns:o=\"urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office\"\nxmlns:x=\"urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel\"\nxmlns:ss=\"urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet\"\nxmlns:html=\"http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40\">\n<Worksheet ss:Name=\"Sheet1\">\n<Table ss:ExpandedColumnCount=\"";
    NSString *columncount = @"\" ss:ExpandedRowCount=\"";
    NSString *rowcount = @"\" x:FullColumns=\"1\"x:FullRows=\"1\">\n";

    NSString *rowStart = @"<Row>\n";
    NSString *rowEnde = @"\n</Row>\n";

    NSString *stringStart = @"<Cell><Data ss:Type=\"String\">";
    NSString *stringEnde = @"</Data></Cell>";

    NSString *numberStart = @"<Cell><Data ss:Type=\"Number\">";
    NSString *numberEnde = @"</Data></Cell>";

    NSString *footer = @"</Table>\n</Worksheet>\n</Workbook>";

    NSString *xlsstring = @"";

    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Form" inManagedObjectContext:context];

    [request setEntity:entity];

    NSArray *arr = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];

    int numberOfRows = 1;
    int numberOfCols = 2;

    for (Form *form in arr) {
        numberOfRows = numberOfRows + 1;
    }

    xlsstring = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%i%@%i%@", header, numberOfCols, columncount, numberOfRows, rowcount];
    xlsstring = [xlsstring stringByAppendingFormat:@"%@%@Patient number%@%@Name%@%@", rowStart, stringStart, stringEnde, stringStart, stringEnde, rowEnde];

    for (Form *form in arr) {
        xlsstring = [xlsstring stringByAppendingFormat:@"%@%@%@%@%@%@%@%@", rowStart, numberStart, form.pnumber, numberEnde, stringStart, form.name, stringEnde, rowEnde];
    }
    xlsstring = [xlsstring stringByAppendingFormat:@"%@", footer];

    [xlsstring writeToFile:@"/Users/***/Desktop/form.xls" atomically:YES encoding:NSISOLatin1StringEncoding error:nil];
}
```

Does anyone have any idea why this might be so, or even a solution for this error?

Comment: have you considered using a .CSV file, they are really easy to make and open on both Excel and Numbers

Comment: yes, I have. But the Excel file gets some formatting for better reading in the future. Thanks for that fast answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Numbers won't import the Excel XML format. (See [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/3357/can-numbers-09-import-an-excel-xml-file).) It'll import the Excel native format, but writing that isn't going to be a trivial job.

Could you make your app have the option of both Excel XML (for Excel users) and CSV (for Numbers users)?

Comment: Okay, this option I also thought about. But I would like to format the headline of each collum. Probably I could give the option to export to *.numbers? Is it really untrivial to make an real *.xls file? Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Regarding making real Excel files, you could take a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3516129/read-data-from-excel-file-in-objective-c-iphone/3594651#3594651).

Comment: Regarding writing .numbers files directly, you'd have to do a bit of reverse engineering. The iWork XML schema _used_ to be public: there's an old programming guide for it [here](http://www.filibeto.org/unix/macos/lib/dev/documentation/AppleApplications/Conceptual/iWork2-0_XML/iWork2-0_XML.pdf). However, that's from the first version of iWork, which was Pages and Keynote only, before Numbers came along. The format has also changed since then. However, if you're going to reverse engineer it yourself, it might help you get started.

Comment: I've just been looking through the XML format for a simple Numbers spreadsheet. The file for a blank spreadsheet is 1.1MB, and the xpath to a cell where I typed some text content is `/ls:document/ls:workspace-array/ls:workspace/ls:page-info/sf:layers/sf:layer/sf:drawables/sf:tabular-info/sf:tabular-model/sf:grid/sf:datasource/sf:t/sf:ct/sfa:s`. I'm sure it could be deciphered but I don't envy you trying!

Comment: Many thanks for your answers. Well, I think, I will take the csv/xls solution for the first time.