# Watch XLS with Xml created with QuickLook framework iOS

Tags: ios, xml, xls, quicklook

I have created a XLS with advises of:

[Export data to *.xls file by using xml to create the file on an iOS 5 App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10735805/export-data-to-xls-file-by-using-xml-to-create-the-file-on-an-ios-5-app)

and

http://mobile.experts-exchange.com/Apple/Hardware/iPhone/A_4575-Create-Excel-Supported-XML-in-iPhone-using-Xcode.html

If I open it with openOffice, it works perfectly.

My problem is I´d like open that file with QuickLook framework.

Looking for in Apple Guidelines about QLPreviewController Class Reference:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Reference/QLPreviewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html

It says:
A Quick Look preview controller can display previews for the following items:

Microsoft Office documents (Office ‘97 and newer)

But I tried with the same file xlsx which I could open with openoffice and it didn´t work with QLPreviewController.

Answer (score 0):

If you have any doubt with the file and Quick Look supporting it, try to use Quick Look in Finder (on OS X) see if it can display the file, or with Numbers. And finally, try to send the file to your iOS device via email and see if the Mail app can display the file.

If it doesn't, it might be that the Quick Look underlying conversion engine does not support your file format (either it's corrupted in a subtle way that Open Office can handle or it's a special format that Quick Look does not understand).

Either way, you should likely go to [Apple's Bug Report site](http://bugreport.apple.com/) and file a bug, attaching your file to it.

Comment: Thanks for the advise, I will try, and I will share with you the results. Thanks a lot