# How to correctly tell iOS that my app handles CSV?

Tags: ios

In my Info.plist file I have this:

```
<key>CFBundleDocumentTypes</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
        <string>CSV Data</string>
        <key>LSHandlerRank</key>
        <string>Alternate</string>
        <key>LSItemContentTypes</key>
        <array>
            <string>public.comma-separated-values-text</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
</array>
```

Which *mostly* works.

The screw case happened when somebody took an Excel spreadsheet on Windows, saved it as CSV, and emailed it to their iPad, for import into my app.

The mail client gave the attachment a MIME type of application/vnd.ms-excel, which could be considered incorrect.  I would expect that MIME type to be used for files actually in Excel format, not for just any file that was exported from Excel.

In the iOS mail app, I long-press on the attachment to open the file in some other app.  Here is where things to wrong.

My app gets included in the list of available apps.  I'm not sure whether to call this correct or incorrect.  The file is CSV and has a .csv suffix, so I'm happy my app was invited to the party.  But...

If I then click on our app to open that file, it "doesn't work", meaning that the OpenURL method in my AppDelegate never gets called.

In this case, two wrongs do make a right.  If I lie and add com.microsoft.excel.xls to LSItemContentTypes, then it "works", meaning that (1) my app still gets listed in the Open In dialog, and (2) iOS actually gives me the file, and (3) because the file isn't really in Excel format but CSV, my app deals with it just fine.

But now the app is claiming to support actual Excel files, which it does not do.

This seems like a bug in iOS.  Either don't list me in the dialog or actually give me the file.

Or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar problem using passkit and found no solution to accept malformed MIME types. I suggest that you add a converter from Excel to CSV and accept Excel files! (:

Here's another post to help you with that:
[Read data from Excel file in Objective-C (iPhone)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3516129/read-data-from-excel-file-in-objective-c-iphone)