# Can an iOS app create and regularly access a google spreadsheet?

Tags: swift, google-api

I would like to build a simple app that allows a user to add new entries into a simple and specifically designed Google spreadsheet in a very simple and controlled manner.

It will never delete from the spreadsheet, only alter three cells at a time, and receive the input information from a screen within the app.  The spreadsheet is also created by the app, and several column headings and very simple calculations are setup. Obviously the user must have a Google identity.

I've never attempted to program an app before, and don't want to waste my time, so I'd like to know if this simplistic level of control/creation of a Google spreadsheet from within and iOS app is possible?

This app would almost (probably) be only for my personal use.

Comment: Try this link out and see if this helps?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20542146/import-google-spreadsheet-cell-data-to-xcode-uitextfield

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is doable. You can use gdata APIs. Check Google Data APIs Objective-C Client Library.
https://code.google.com/p/gdata-objectivec-client/